# Are comments allowed in email address domain part?

Tags: email, smtp

Comments are allowed in email address local part - for example `cat(veryangry)lives@inmyhouse.com`, but is it possible to add comments in email domain part like - `catlives@(veryangry)inmyhouse.com`? Will SMTP servers accept that?

Just tried on POSTFIX - email comments are rejected even in email local part... In domain part accepted, but I think those comments are not recognized (or POSTFIX email filter is not so strict).

Revising my SMTP server email filter.. Now all email comments are removed, but if message is relayed - it is unclear if they should be also sent. It could be that many SMTP servers will not accept such email.. Trying to find some info in RFCs..

Comment: I think it is wholly dependent on what SMTP server is accepting messages for `inmyhouse.com`.

Comment: Oh boy, how many of y’all’s fancy email validation regexs support this?

Comment: RFC5322 mentions "Note: A liberal syntax for the domain portion of addr-spec is given here.  However, the domain portion contains addressing information specified by and used in other protocols (e.g., [RFC1034], [RFC1035], [RFC1123], [RFC5321]).  It is therefore incumbent upon implementations to conform to the syntax of addresses for the context in which they are used."

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Crazy, but it's legal, from [RFC2822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt) (from chapter: A.5. White space, comments, and other oddities):

`From: Pete(A wonderful \) chap) <pete(his account)@silly.test(his host)>`

*..The above example is aesthetically displeasing, but perfectly legal...*

Answer (score 7):

actually, comments are allowed, whereas I have to add that - generally speaking - the comment itself should be either at the end or at the beginning of each part:

```
(comment)local.part@domain.part.tld
local.part(comment)@domain.part.tld
local.part@(comment)domain.part.tld 
local.part@domain.part.tld(comment)
```

I think, if there is a comment inbetween it should be surrounded by ' " ' + dots:

```
local."(comment)".part@domain.part.tld
```

as special characters like "(" must be in ' "'.

There is a great summary on wikipedia with references.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address

Whereas for me, the questions is left whether the comment can span the whole local part.